# Calculating the possibility of having sequential numbers in randomly picked cards

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, algorithms

This is the question (3):

[image]

I am thinking  something like this:

Answer will appeal when the probability of having no sequential numbers in pickings decrease below 50%.

So if I assume that I picked first number as 50, then possibility of second pick to be non sequential is:
$\frac{97}{99}$. 3rd is $\frac{94}{98}$, 4th is $\frac{91}{97}$and so on.
Therefore if when $\frac{97}{99}\times\frac{94}{98}\times\frac{91}{97} ...$ hits below 1/2, the iteration count + 1 is the answer. But I am assured that it is not the answer. So could you explain me what is the correct method to solve this problem?

Comment: See:http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for improve formatting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From $100$ balls, remove k of them, then $100-k$ balls remain.

$\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet..... \uparrow\bullet \uparrow$

The $k$ removed balls can be inserted at any of the $(100-k+1)$ uparroows w/o being sequential,
and if you *now* number the balls, the $k$ inserted balls will always be non-sequential.

Thus P(none of the $k$ chosen numbers is sequential)$= \frac{\dbinom{101-k}{k}}{\dbinom{100}k}$, and we want this to be $<0.5$

$k = 9$ gives the first value below $0.5$

---

ALTERNATIVE EXPLANATION based on **drawing** rather than **insertion**

Here is an explanation in black and white to address multiple queries:

We shall illustrate with $n=7, k = 3$, chosen balls black, unchosen balls white.

There will be $4$ unchosen balls $\quad\circ\quad\circ\quad\circ\quad\circ$

The $3$ chosen black balls *must have been drawn from any $3$ of the $5$ gaps including the two ends:*
$\;-\circ\;-\circ\;-\circ\;-\circ-$

**All** such draws will have the black balls non-sequential

The numerator of $\binom53 = \binom{n-k+1}{k}$ thus represents all permissible drawals.

The denominator represents drawals of **any** $3$ balls.

Comment: This is cool but I do not understand the reasoning. If you are removing balls only to insert them elsewhere and only THEN label everything, what was the point of removing them in the first place? What exactly is this counting? Even if you move $k$ balls out of sequence, what guarantee is there that you draw them from the full set?

Comment: Yeap, I believe the solution is much more complex than combinations.

Comment: @user51819: $\binom{101−k}{k}$ counts **all** subsets  of length $k$  from a string of $100$ which are not sequential. Removing, inserting, and labelling the balls is just a neat way of **identifying** such subsets.

Comment: @Alper91: It is not just "combinations" , there is a denominator, too. Why don't you just work out for a small example, say with $n=5$, and various values of k, and try to see how $\frac{\binom{6-k}{k}}{\binom{5}{k}}$ works out..

Comment: The number of ways to pick $k$ cards from a set of $100$ such that no two cards are next to each other, right? I just fail to see how that works. The player chooses the cards randomly, so how does re-shuffling the deck have any impact?

Comment: Lets calculate the P of two drawings. There are two sub P. If we pick 1 or 100 first(P = $\frac{2}{100}$), then second draw has P of $\frac{98}{99}$ and if we draw 2 to 99 first (P = $\frac{98}{100}$), second draw has P of $\frac{97}{99}$ therefore in total P of drawing 2 non-seq number is $\frac{2}{100} \times \frac{98}{99} + \frac{98}{100} \times \frac{97}{99}$ = $\frac{98}{100}$ Yeap it works. Let me check for 5. It will take a while.

Comment: @user51819: We are **not** trying to reshuffle, merely using a slick way to count for the numerator. Let's take $n=6, k = 3$. We need to count $1-3-5,1-3-6,1-4-6, \;and\;2-4-6$ which adds up to $4$ cases. The formula evolved gives $\binom42=6$.

Comment: Yes It works!! But, really though! I am still having trouble to understand your logic. If I understand why there is 100 - k + 1 uparrows situation I believe I will see the big picture.

Comment: For $n=6, k=3,\;\; \uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\;\;$ The $(n-k) = (6-3) =3$ balls left have $(n-k+1) =4$ gaps including the ends, where balls can be inserted (shown by uparrows) without being sequential.

Comment: @user51819: I have added an explanation in "black and white".

Comment: @trueblueanil I do not mean to be a nuisance, but I still do not follow. I understand that re-folding the black balls into the white in between the gaps prevents them from being sequential, but how does this affect anything? When you are drawing cards, they are drawn randomly from various parts of the lineup. What's to stop someone from drawing (say) two black balls in a row just because they happen to be in different parts of the lineup? How has reshuffling changed anything with respect to counting? I know you must be right here but I am struggling to see the intuition.

Comment: @user51819: I have changed the ADDED EXPLANATION from **inserting** chosen balls (which I think is the source of your confusion) to **drawing** chosen balls. I believe this will provide the intuition you seek.

Comment: Aaaahhhhhh that makes sense now! Thank you!

Comment: @user51819: You're welcome ! Just remember that you will come across many answers that use the inserting and numbering method.

Comment: I feel a little dumb but just now I could understand it! It is ingenious! I wrote 800 lines of C++ codes to find the answer (like 10 hours) and you just did the same thing in half hour. Respect!

Comment: Thanks, I am glad you like it !