# Details of how many 3-element subsets of $\{1, 2, ..., 20\}$ exist such that no two consecutive integers are in the same subset?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I do realize that an answer exists already (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1421851/797279), however I was wondering why we do not divide by $3!$, such that  the formula becomes $$\binom{20}{3} - \frac{19 \cdot 18}{3!} + 18$$

My reasoning is that when we choose a $3$-element subset with consecutive elements we go about it in such a process:

- There are $19$ integers with consecutive numbers, thus we have $19$ choices for the first element
- We then have $1$ choice for the second element as we want it to be consecutive number of the first element
- We now have $18$ choices to work with for the third element
- Order doesn't matter for the set thus we divide by the number of ways to permute the elements

Comment: .'There are $19$ integers with consecutive numbers, thus we have $19$ choices for the first element '.Yes there are ,but here note that while taking the choices we are not considering the order of elements in each pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't divide by $3!$ because your way of choosing the triplets is in $1-1$ correspondance with the sets you are looking for.

Let me explain it a bit more in detail:

Frist, let us look at the case where in the set $\{a,b,c\}$ only $2$ of the elements are consecutive, that is (after relabeling if needed) $\{a,b,b+1\}$ with $a\neq b-1$, $a\neq b+2$. There is only one way you could have chosen that particular set.

For the sets of the form $\{a,a+1,a+2\}$ is a bit different because there are (exactly) $2$ ways you could have chosen this particular set. That is the reason of the last "$+18$" in the formula.